# Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence: RestTemplate

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, utf-8

I am integrating third party API using Rest Template, which will send the response in the format of XML. But for some of the request, getting the below error.

> Could not unmarshal to [class com.xxx.SearchResponse]:
>   null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException\n - with
>   linked
>   exception:\n[com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException:
>   Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

I tried with contentType as "application/xml", "text/plain", "text/xml" , "text/xml,charset=UTF-8"

Only for some of the response, getting this error and also xml response has too many lines. Hard to detect the characters facing this problem. I guess some content type i am missing it.

**XML Element:**

```
<search-response xmlns="" xmlns:info="" xmlns:common="">
<search-response>
```

When i hit the third party API in the postman, getting the content type as "text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1"

Comment: A `MalformedByteSequenceException` means the server does not send UTF8. Post the (filtered) response somewhere we can see it

Comment: Service is sending ISO-8859-1, you are treating as UTF-8. That's all there is to it. You need to read respect the content type you saw in postman.

Comment: I tried to set like ""Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1", still getting the same error.